# How to read line of file until end using system calls in C?

Tags: c, io

I'm trying to read a file line by line by comparing the currently read character with `\n` (end of line symbol). The characters of that line are stored in a buffer.

I'm confused how to handle at the same time the buffer, where I keep the current line and the check with the end of line character. That's what I use the `indexCurrentSymbol` for, to always the the last symbol of the buffer and see if it's `\n`.

Please not that I'm supposed to achieve this with basic system calls (so no library functions that read a full line).

The input is

```
Animal, Size
Dog, Big
Duck, Small
Mouse, Tiny
Horse, Huge
```

I'm ignoring all error checks for files that might not be available on purpose to be able to focus on the task.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { 

    // Open file to read line.
    int input = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
    char buf[100];
    int read_bytes = read(input, &buf, 1); 
    int indexCurrentSymbol = 0;
    while (buf[indexCurrentSymbol] != '\n') {
        // read(input, buf, 1);    // Correction based on comment.
        read(input, &buf[indexCurrentSymbol], 1);
        indexCurrentSymbol++;
    }   

    close(input);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you keep overwriting the first character in the buffer?

Comment: hmm, your right. I now increment the writing position in the buffer using the `indexCurrentSymbol` counter. I guess that makes more sense, while still not solves the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a modified program version that allows to read the whole file
(note that error processing is *not* enough and there is *no* check on `buf` maximum size):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { 


    char buf[100];
    int indexCurrentSymbol = 0;
    int read_bytes;
    int line_read=0;
    int file_read=0;

    // Open file to read line.
    int input = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
    if (input < 0) 
    perror("open");

    buf[0] = '\0';
    while (file_read == 0) {

        read_bytes = read(input, &buf[indexCurrentSymbol], 1);
        if (read_bytes == -1) 
           perror("read while: -1");
        if (read_bytes == 0) 
            file_read = 1;

        if (buf[indexCurrentSymbol] == '\n')
             printf("current buf=\n%s\n", buf);

        indexCurrentSymbol++;
    }   

    printf("final buf=\n%s\n", buf);
    close(input);
    return 0;
}
```

With:

```
$ cat tread.dat
Animal, Size
Dog, Big
Duck, Small
Mouse, Tiny
Horse, Huge
```

I get:

```
$ ./tread tread.dat
current buf=
Animal, Size

current buf=
Animal, Size
Dog, Big

current buf=
Animal, Size
Dog, Big
Duck, Small

current buf=
Animal, Size
Dog, Big
Duck, Small
Mouse, Tiny

current buf=
Animal, Size
Dog, Big
Duck, Small
Mouse, Tiny
Horse, Huge

final buf=
Animal, Size
Dog, Big
Duck, Small
Mouse, Tiny
Horse, Huge
```